# Only one instance of object for all visitors?

Tags: asp.net

I have a dedicated server with a Skype client running on it. I intend to use the Skype COM API to make an AJAX-based live-chat on my website.

However, for this to work, I need an object to be initialized only once for all visitors, and I need to be able to use that very same object across visitors too. How can this be done?

Comment: try: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Application["keyhere"] object to simulate singleton properly.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can put it on your application

> System.Web.HttpApplication

class and instance it on

> Application_Start()

or

> Application_Init()

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a singleton pattern. However you will get global state, it would probably better to share the chat messages using a database of some sort. Global state is tricky to test.